# Is Faraday's law due to relativity ? A question from Griffith

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-induction

In Griffith's EM, section 7.2.1 includes following pictures to talk about Faraday's law , where by Faraday's law I will be referring to its differential form rather than integral form.

[image]

In the images (b) and (c) I can understand either the magnet moves or strength of it changes so that

$$\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t} \neq \textbf{0} $$

From which a a potential is induced.

But in the picture (a) , the same term is always zero, and i can't say why does electric fields arise.

It is perhaps due to some relativistic effect about current , but I can't do give a technical answer, (if you could pls :) )

But, i can just say that bcs effect is observable in (b), by special relativity same thing must happen. (yet, why i should have started with picture (b) as my reference frame?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case a) is different: here EMF in the circuit is not due to induced electric field $\mathbf E_i$ (which is negligible here), but due to motion of part of the circuit in external static magnetic field, thus it is better called *motional EMF*.  The motional force per unit charge is $\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$, where $\mathbf v$ is velocity of the conductor.

Faraday's law in its integral form is valid for both kinds of EMF or any combination of the two.

Comment: Ok, I would just like to comment that definition of emf should be work required on unit charge on the loop for $\textbf{fixed time (frozen time)}$, in that case it makes sense otherwise B seems to do work. The reason I say this is, that B does work is why I went to think of some induced E.

Comment: Yes, that is how emf is defined, for single time. The integral of the motional force intensity, whether $\mathbf E_i$, or $\mathbf v\times \mathbf B$, has to be done at single time. $B$ does not do work.

Answer (score 0):

Parts (a) and (b) are different only by a frame of reference. In one case, the loop is moving, and in the other case, it is the source of field.

Although yes, if you have a source of moving charge, then the generation of the magnetic field can be seen as a relativistic effect. Let me explain.

Say I have an infinite wire carrying current $I$ and another charge $q$ at some distance $r$ from the wire moving at velocity $v$ w.r.t. the wire (see figure below).

[image]

Above, you see two frames $S$ (the frame at which the wire is at rest) and $S'$ (charge is at rest). In the $S$-frame, there is a magnetic force on the particle and is directed toward the wire. However, in the $ S'$ frame, there can be no magnetic force on the particle because its velocity is zero.

But the force should exist in both frames of reference; after all, the change in the separation $r$ should be the same for both frames. So, what would be the source of the acceleration in the $ S'$ frame where there is no magnetic force?

If you have learned relativity, then you might know that moving frames experience length contraction as viewed by an observer at rest. Similarly, when the charge in the $S'$-frame sees the charge in the wire, it seems its length is contracted. But wait, it is only the negative current (in the wire) that will experience a length contraction after all the positive charge in the wire is not moving w.r.t. $S'$-frame.

As a result, w.r.t. $S'$, the wire has a higher negative charge density than positive one. This imbalance in charge density produces an electrical force on the charge $q$ as viewed by $S'$.

So, in conclusion, the magnetic force in one frame is the electrical force in the other frame. In other words, electric and magnetic fields can be seen on equal footing.  For more, see section 13.6 of [Feynman Vol II](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html).

Comment: I found this answer useful because it gives resource and an example, but I think above answer is the right answer for the question.